# Which program is not used for archiving?

Tags: archive

Which program is not used for archiving ?

Gzip, tar, cpio or zip ?

I thought cpio is used to copy files from the archive that is why i am a little confused. Out of the four programs which one is not used for archiving or is it a trick question? to be honest i have a homework and i a not sure what the answer is..

Thanks

Comment: Assignment question!!

Comment: I think I'd use any of them for archiving, depending on the situation. `cpio` is somewhat long in the tooth, but still around and working "mostly satisfactorily".

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, you have to consider the two aspects in which these four tools can be involved:

- file archiving
- file compression

You have to find out which utility can not be used to provide an archive file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that's (your teacher's) a dumb, ambiguous and poorly worded question.

`tar`, `zip` and and `cpio` are probably the ones meant to be the archiving ones as they create files that can contain an archive with several files (with their content, path and metadata) in them.

`gzip` is only meant for compression, so can store only one content by itself. It does store the original file name (not path) and some metadata though. So it could still be considered as an archiver but whose archives can only store one member.

You can also concatenate gz files (though generally only the first file name is easily retrievable). It's also *used for archiving* in that it's typically used to compress the output of `tar`.

Comment: Thank you. I think the answer is Gzip. When i receive my results i will share :)